# Bind a connectionString to every DataProvider constructor OR inject a connection interface

Tags: dependency-injection, sqlconnection

My Services are all accessing DataProvider classes. Each DataProvider constructor gets the connectionString as parameter injected with a DI tool.

Where is the advantage of hiding the connectionString in a IConnectionString interface and inject this interface instead of the connectionString?

Just consider for your answer: I do not use any interface to access my DataProvider classes. And these classes do not use IDbConnection.

I completely tie myself to the MS SQL Server and this is what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Injection is not only because of replacability. Its much more about testability.

If you are tied 100% to SQL Server then your tests would also be bound to Sql Server and thats not very good and makes things complicated.

If you don't use any interfaces for your dataprovider, than using interfaces fo connectionstrings would bring any benefits from my point of view.

The idea of injecting components is the depedency injection principle.
s. also [Martin Fowlers Post](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

But even if you will ever use MS SQl Server I would strongly recommend using some kind of Gateway / Repository pattern.
That would give you such a better test experience and more reliable software.

As a refrence i can suggest you the cleancoders webcasts from uncle bob (Robert C Martin

http//www.cleancoders.com

Comment: "But even if you will ever use MS SQl Server" This sounds as I would have never said that I only want to use MS SQL Server. You know that I do testing? :p Ok lets assume I do integrating testing (what I really do) What happens here is that for every service I create one/multiple dataprovider classes and pass the connectionString in their constructor manually. There is nothing bound to M$ SQL. The string is an abstraction and can containg every database path. As I said I will stick with MS SQL. Databases are evaluated and then decided. Not something that you change by 50/50% chances ;-)

Comment: Yeah right. I just want to point out, that the main benefit would be testability :-)

Comment: Seems you have not fully understood my opinion what I said before. There is no benefit of testability. I can test a concrete dataprovider injected with a connectionString/IConnectionString interface to the same degree. If you have another opinion please provide a sample to show the benefit, thanks.